# Complicated text compare in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table result

```
---------------------------------------------------------
coupon id| required_product_ids|used_product_in_this_year
---------------------------------------------------------
1        |1,2,3,10             |2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13
```

How can I check if `used_product_in_this_year` has at least one `required_product_ids` by SQL.
I tried somethings with SQL like keyword but did not success.

Comment: This is a poor table design. Better insert separate rows for the products. This will create complexity only. Use computed column.

Comment: Chapter 2 "Jaywalking" of Bill Karwin's excellent book "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"  covers this topic fairly well.     https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557

Comment: A beginners Design  i guess..

Comment: Thanks for yours reply@spencer7593 @At-2016 but my working project is old.

Comment: try to use contains

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I have edited. Thanks you @jarlh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native SQL construct for performing this type of comparison.

To find a single value in a comma separated list, MySQL provides a `FIND_IN_SET` function. But to handle a comma separated list of values, to check each one, to see if it's in a list, each separate value would need to be supplied into `FIND_IN_SET`. And that would be unweildy.

If the hard and fast requirement is to handle this comparison in a SQL statement, I'd recommend writing a function to do the comparison.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE FUNCTION upity_halo_rpi(upity VARCHAR(4000), rpi VARCHAR(4000))
 RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
 BEGIN
   -- TODO: extract first element of upity 
   -- TODO: check if element is in rpi list
   -- if it is found in the list
      RETURN TRUE;
   -- otherwise, split off next element
   -- loop through all elements
   -- if loop completes without finding a match is found, fall out
      RETURN FALSE;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

With the function written, and thoroughly tested, it could be used in a SQL statement. To return a column that indicates that the row "has at least one"...

```
 SELECT t.coupon id
      , t.required_product_ids
      , t.used_product_in_this_year
      , upity_halo_rpi(t.used_product_in_this_year,t.required_product_ids) AS halo
   FROM result t
```

To return:

```
coupon id  required_product_ids  used_product_in_this_year  halo
---------  --------------------  ------------------------  -----
1          1,2,3,10              2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13      1
```

I'm not going to write the function. I'm just demonstrating a possible approach. One possible answer to "how" this type of comparison operation could be  performed within a SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, without changing your database structure.

In MYSQL (Tested):

```
select * from TableName 
    where concat(',', used_product_in_this_year, ',') regexp concat(',',replace(required_product_ids,',',',|,'),',')
```

Using this Regex structure with your table and manipulating the data with a some mysql string functions.

I don't recommend your database structure, but I like puzzles and this one was fun, thanks for the challenge.

Comment: sorry for offtop, but if you really like sql puzzles check sql-ex.com

Comment: thanks you.Sorry for my lack of information.I'm using mssql instead of mysql. But thanks for your answer, i will try this one with mssql.

Comment: You tagged the question as `mysql` so I assumed it was. I'm not sure how you can do it in mssql. I don't use that database :(